# Steady-state Error Definition

Tags: control-theory

In the textbooks and reference material which I have been using during my course on *control systems*, a common definition of steady-state error is as follows:
$$E(s)=R(s)-C(s)$$
where E(s) is the error (and also the signal carried forward directly from the summing node), R(s) input and C(s) output.

This definition has the slightly unsettling effect of yielding a negative error in the case that the output is *above* the reference signal, and vice versa. Wouldn't it be more logical to flip the RHS expression?

Is there any particular reasoning behind selecting this convention?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> *where E(s) is the error (and also the signal carried forward directly
>   from the summing node), R(s) input and C(s) output.*

The error is "demand" minus "output" and the output and the demand are desired to be equal hence, the "thing that does the math" is a subtractor: -

[image]

Picture from [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/control_systems/control_systems_quick_guide.htm).

> *This definition has the slightly unsettling effect of yielding a
>   negative error in the case that the output is above the reference
>   signal, and vice versa.*

If the controller, feedback network and plant (as shown above) are non-inverting, then "demand" minus "output" is absolutely correct in that the error produced drives the system towards closer accuracy.

Comment: I used "summing node" as a catch-all term for "the thing that does the math", without regard for the sign of its inputs, as ultimately subtraction is summation with negatives, so I don't think it was here that my understanding fell short.

Comment: Ah, viewing the error as the "driving force" as opposed to a simple error (in the English sense) gives some insight. It would therefore drive the system's output down for an output which is too high. Thanks.

Comment: Most folk regard the controller and plant as having a default "sign" as being positive. Slightly less than most folk might regard the feedback network as having a positive "sign" also and so, if you flipped the subtractor by adding a stage of error inversion (for instance) then you would have positive feedback and an almost instantaneously unstable system. The sign is important.

Answer (score 2):

To me, the convention here makes much more sense than what you propose, but I think that's really just personal opinion!

However, this definition simply makes the necessary correction have the same sign as the error, and that, I feel, has a beneficial effect on the simplicity of the system block diagram. Again, pure opinion – I don't think there's a "factual" reason; after all, every proportionality can have a negative sign, so there's nothing inherently forcing any specific signs.

Comment: I know I wasn't alone in class for confusing the sign of the error, but I can see the benefit. For me, an error is always something to be removed (i.e. subtraction) from the output.